# awk syntax error at "=" because variable name is in string?

Tags: awk

`awk` throws an error if I define a variable to be a string, and that variable name is in the string. Why?

minimal reproducible example:

```
echo "stuff" |  \
awk '{
   dir = "/somewhere"
   log = dir "/log.gz" 
}'  FS="\t"  OFS="\t"
```

gives the error:

```
awk: cmd. line:3:    log = dir "/log.gz"
awk: cmd. line:3:        ^ syntax error
```

However, if I rename the variable `log` to `mlog`, as follows:

```
echo "stuff" |  \
awk '{
   dir = "/somewhere"
   mlog = dir "/log.gz" 
}'  FS="\t"  OFS="\t"
```

then there is no error and it exits successfully.

What is going on here?

---

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `log` as a variable name in your Program which is NOT allowed(its a reserved keyword in `awk` programming). When we see `man awk` we get this:

> log(expr)     The natural logarithm function.

Try changing your variable name here.

As an example: When I change its name to l_log its not showing any errors now. I have kept its name as `l_log` you could keep it as per your requirement.

```
echo "stuff" | 
awk '{
   dir="/somewhere"
   l_log=dir "/log.gz" 
}'  FS="\t"  OFS="\t"
```